# how to find the angle of the certain point

Tags: javascript, svg, geometry

I drawn the svg circle using start and endangle as follow,

```
document.getElementById("circle").setAttribute("d", describeArc(150, 150, 100, 180, 360));
            function getPathArc(center, start, end, radius) {
                        end = end - 0.0001;
                        var degree = end - start;
                        degree = degree < 0 ? (degree + 360) : degree;
                        var clockWise = (degree < 180) ? 0 : 1;
                        return getPiePath(center, degreeToLocation(start, radius, center), degreeToLocation(end, radius, center), radius, clockWise);
            }
            function getPiePath(center, start, end, radius, clockWise) {
                        return 'M ' + start.x + ' ' + start.y + ' A ' + radius + ' ' + radius + ' 0 ' + clockWise + ' 1 ' + end.x + ' ' + end.y;
            };          
            function degreeToLocation(degree, radius, center) {
                    var radian = (degree * Math.PI) / 180;
                    return { 
                        'x' : Math.cos(radian) * radius + center.x,
                        'y': Math.sin(radian) * radius + center.y
                    };
            }           
            function describeArc(x, y, radius, startAngle, endAngle){
                var endAngle = endAngle - startAngle;
                startAngle = startAngle <= 0 ? (360 + startAngle) % 360 : startAngle % 360;
                endAngle = endAngle < 0 ? (360 + endAngle + startAngle) % 360 : Math.abs(endAngle + startAngle) % 360;
                    var direction = getPathArc({'x': x, 'y': y}, startAngle, endAngle, radius);
                    var d = direction;
                    return d;       
            }
```

here is the sample https://jsfiddle.net/ndmsqmao/3/

i need to draw the one tick line for that circle for specified point.

for example let us consider,

if it's value is start from 50 to 100 mean i need to draw the one tick line for 66th value.. how to acheive this?

[image]

Comment: Would this help (https://codepen.io/MitchJackson94/pen/vHzEf)?

Comment: thanks but that one is shown only the angle of the circle... i need to show the 40th value that mean, startAngle is 180 endAngle is 36 start value is 50 and end value is 100 mean i need to point out the 66th value

Comment: @evolutionxbox also i have tried to calculate the degree of the exact point some this is missing from my side

if value is 75 mean it should return 90 degree.
angle =  (((Math.abs(value) / (100)) * (360))) + 180;

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps...

```
var minValue = 50, maxValue = 100, value = 66,
    minAngle = 180, maxAngle = 360, angle;

angle = minAngle + (value - minValue) / (maxValue - minValue) * (maxAngle - minAngle);

alert(angle);
```

Comment: if  startAngle and endAngle is same we can't able to get the angle of the certain point. for that caluculation..

I have tried this calculation this one is working fine,


var degree = endAngle - startAngle;
        degree = degree < 0 ? (degree + 360) : degree;
        return (value * (degree / (maximumValue - minimumValue))) + startAngle;

Answer (score 1):

I hope i understand your Question...

```
var min = 50;
var max = 100;
var value = 66;

var angle = 180/(max-min)*(value-min)+180;

console.log (angle);
```

Comment: Hi Thanks,

just now i found that calculation.. 

the below calculation working fine,

 var totalDegree = endAngle - startAngle;

 totalDegree  =  totalDegree  <  0  ?  (totalDegree  +  360)  :  totalDegree;
 
var degree (value * (degree / (maximumValue - minimumValue))) + startAngle;